# Help installing a package for the "Community Search Basics - Make Better Decisions with Analytics" Trailhead Challenge

Tags: community, trailhead

I'm wondering if anyone can help?

There's a [post thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G000000BgbBQAS) in the Developer Community, but I thought I'd try my luck here.

The Trailhead Challenge requires me to download the `Spring ’17 Salesforce Community Management Package` for Communities with Chatter.  However, this isn't available - I tried with the Summer '17 and now the Winter '18 and am getting the same error message each time I try and install it.

I've tried installing in an incognito browser window (as suggested in Trailhead help) and also created a brand new Trailhead Playground and a brand new DEV org.
In my Trailhead Playground I got the `URL No longer exists` error:

[image]

But in the DEV org I got a `Missing Organization Feature:Networks` error:

[image]

Can anyone help so I can try and complete the Challenge and Trail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to [Enable Salesforce Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_enable.htm&type=0) in your DEV org before installing the package..

Comment: Thank you SO much Rahul...I've posted in so many places and that's such a simple answer!!  I couldn't see it anywhere on the Trailhead instructions, so must have missed it.  I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Cheers, glad to be of any help. Was my lucky guess. Quite often it says feature is missing with some object name, Networks is part of communities. Still message is not descriptive enough.